# Swing Dialogbox html formatting 'cutting off' half of the content

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

I have a dialog which I wish make a specific part **bold**.
I know I have to do this with `html` however I seem to be losing half of the dialog message when I do this.

Original (No bold):

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    private final static String NEW_LINE = System
            .getProperty("line.separator");
    public void someMethodDisplayDialog(String string1, String string2, String string3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "An problem occured: " + string1
                        + NEW_LINE 
                        + string2 + " Error: "
                        + string3,
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Lets say:

- `string1 = "Wrong Key!"`,
- `string2 = "Input"`,
- `string = "Z key pressed"`.

In the dialog box this displays:

---

A problem occurred: Wrong Key!
Input Error: Z key pressed

---

I want to bold the "**Input Error:**" section. I have this code:

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "An problem occured: " + string1
                        + NEW_LINE + "<html><b>" 
                        + string2 + " Error:</b></html> "
                        + string3,
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

When run, this bolds what I want, but *'cuts off'* off the rest, eg. `string3` is not displayed.
I have tried putting the closing `</b></html>` tags after `string3`. 
Everything is displayed, but `string3` is also bold, which I do not want!

I am I missing something blatantly obvious here? I am not sure why this is happening?

Comment: 1) That string will not trigger HTML formatting, since the `<html>` part needs to be the first part of the string.. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it already told by @Andrew Thompson your message **must** be started with `<html>` tag. So your code should look like:

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "<html>An problem occured: " + string1
                    + "<br><b>" 
                    + string2 + " Error:</b> "
                    + string3 + "</html>",
            "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Is it considered better practice to utilise html tags, eg. `<br>` in place of a Java platform dependent newline (`System.getProperty("line.separator");` or `System.lineSeperator();`), if html is being used within the string? For example, if I had what I had above, but moved the `</html>` to the last line so the last line read: `+ string3 + "</html>"`, the same result is achieved.

Comment: I guess the question is more so asking, if `html` is used somewhere in the string, should the whole string be processed as `html`.

Comment: Happy 4K (I wasn't the one to push you over the limit)! Well earned.. :) @Dan No. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. You've already answered this question in your comment. I've simply explained your answer.

Answer (score 0):

add a + sign after string3
edit: your /html tag was cutting off string 3

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "An problem occured: " + string1
                        + NEW_LINE + "<html><b>" 
                        + string2 + " Error:</b>"
                        + string3 + "Error:</html>",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```